# What query will select rows for months that are more than a certain percent different from the previous month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table representing a car traveling a route, broken up into segments:

```
CREATE TABLE travels (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     segmentID int,
     month int,
     year int,
     avgSpeed int
);

-- sample data
INSERT INTO travels (segmentID, month, year, avgSpeed) 
  VALUES
(15,1,2014,80),
(15,1,2014,84),
(15,1,2014,82),
(15,2,2014,70),
(15,2,2014,68),
(15,2,2014,66);
```

The above schema and sample data is also available as a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/183c1/1).

What query will identify segment IDs where average driving speed decreased by more than 10% compared to the previous month?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of what the desired output would look like for the sample data?

Comment: -1 Questions asking for code must demonstrate **some** effort.

Comment: @Kermit sorry, I updated the post, can you please look on it again? thanks

Comment: @TalLevi Effort = attempting to write the query yourself.

Comment: why does month 3 (and 2) have multiple entries?

Comment: @Kermit - I tried believe me, I wouldn't write it if I didn't try it myself.

Comment: @awashburn - because you I can travel as much as I want in one month, so a duplicated month is just fine, but i need to group them by the month

Comment: And consider for months, no year basis... what about going from month 11, 12, 1, 2... No consideration for a year rollover?  Or are the months from 1-n only

Comment: @DRapp you are write but I can suppose that I have only one year for now

Comment: Can you make an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? It takes a little time but shows the community that you have put forth effort in modelling the problem at handle in a self contained piece that is readily tinker-able.

Comment: Edit your question and post the link when you are done creating the SQLFiddle

Comment: @awashburn I edited the post, can you look on it now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution

[Sqlfidle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/183c1/40)

The key is to keep track between previous month and next so i`m doing year*100+month and after group by year and moth  check for difference 1 and 89 in year*100+month field.
Also it is pitty that MySQL does not support CTE and makes query ugly using derivered tables.

Code:

```
select s.month,s.speed,m.month as prevmonth,m.speed as sp, 100-s.speed/m.speed*100 as speeddiff  from
(SELECT segmentid,month,year*100+month as mark,avg(avgSpeed) as speed from travels
group by segmentid,month,year*100+month
) as s
,
(SELECT segmentid,month,year*100+month as mark,avg(avgSpeed) as speed from travels
group by segmentid,month,year*100+month
) as m   
where s.segmentid=m.segmentid and (s.mark=m.mark+1 or s.mark=m.mark+89) and (m.speed-(m.speed/10))>s.speed;
```

CTE code  working on every DB except MySQL

```
with t  as(SELECT segmentid,month,year*100+month as mark,avg(avgSpeed) as speed from travels
group by segmentid,month,year*100+month
)
select s.month,s.speed,m.month as prevmonth,m.speed as sp, 100-s.speed/m.speed*100 as speeddiff from t s 
inner join t m on s.segmentid=m.segmentid and (s.mark=m.mark+1 or s.mark=m.mark+89)
where (m.speed-(m.speed/10))>s.speed;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select each month, join the next month (which is a little convoluted due to your table structure) and find the decrease(/increase). Try the following complex query

```
SELECT 
   t1.segmentID, t1.month, t1.year, AVG(t1.avgSpeed) as avgSpeed1, 
   AVG(t2.avgSpeed) as avgSpeed2,
   1-(AVG(t1.avgSpeed)/AVG(t2.avgSpeed)) as decrease
FROM 
   travels t1
LEFT JOIN 
   travels t2
ON 
   CONCAT(t2.year,'-',LPAD(t2.month,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(1,2,'00')) = DATE_ADD(CONCAT(t1.year,'-',LPAD(t1.month,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(1,2,'00')), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
GROUP BY 
   segmentID, month, year
HAVING 
   avgSpeed1/avgSpeed2 < .9
```

Here is the updated SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/183c1/25

Comment: An inner join will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a self join.  This answer will get you started.  You can work on the details.

```
select somefields
from yourtable t1 join yourtable t2 on t1.something = t2.something
where t1.month = whatever
and t2.month = t1.month + 1
and t2.speed <= t1.speed * .9
```